# Delete / remove am empty array from object from javascript using mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

I have database collection, that looks like this , how to remove this empty array .

Initially I have object in this (HUE) array
Which looks like this

```
  "HUE": [{
        "chartId": "timeseries",
        "name": "TS",
       
    }]
```

, but after deleting the objects, it does not delete the empty array

```
{
 
"userId": "adam",
"charts": {
    "HUE": [],
    "Color": [{
        "chartId": "one",
        "name": "TS",
       
    }]
  }
}
```

P.S I only want to delete the HUE array when its empty

```
     delChartObj.updateOne(
    { 'userId': userId },
    { $pull: query } // this line actually find the chartId and delete it 
  // after the above line, I actually want to check, if after del the object , array became empty, then delete the array too
  , function (err, obj) {
if (err) { res.send.err }

res.status(200).send("Deleted Successfully");
    });
```

Comment: Nope, I didnt find

Comment: You have to use update and $unset

Comment: @MaxiSchvindt $unset  delete the whole array, I only wanna delete the array when its empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the array and then if empty to delete the array, you can do the bellow

```js
db.collection.update(
{
  "$expr" : {
    "$eq" : [ "$userId", "adam" ]
  }
},
[ {
  "$addFields" : {
    "charts.HUE" : {
      "$filter" : {
        "input" : "$charts.HUE",
        "as" : "hue",
        "cond" : {
          "$ne" : [ "$$hue.chartId", "timeseries" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$addFields" : {
    "charts.HUE" : {
      "$cond" : [ {
        "$eq" : [ {
          "$size" : "$charts.HUE"
        }, 0 ]
      }, "$$REMOVE", "$charts.HUE" ]
    }
  }
} ]
)
```

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MX8wwLa6Y8l)

Its pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
Pipeline updates are very powerful, but for simple updates they can be more complicated.

`$$REMOVE` is a system variable, if a field gets this value, its removed.
Here the field gets this value only if empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({userId, 'charts.HUE': {$exists:true, $size:0}}, { $unset: { 'charts.HUE': 1 } })
```

It works -> https://mongoplayground.net/p/uqU7d0Kp2eL

Update: The question changed and this solution is not completely correct. Users have to ask with more details.

Comment: Your solution is working, but how to merge it with my already written code, 
which looks like this.  Updated code in my question

Comment: You have to update your query. Filtering by userId and the first JSON in my example and replace $pull to $unset

Comment: I caught your example, $pull doesn't have the possibility to remove an empty array. So, you can use async/await to generate two queries, the first to update the array and the second to remove empty arrays (I prefer to keep an empty array and remove it for the response). Also, you can read about a bulk updates.